# Why defining a method in main defines it both in Object and in main.singleton_class?

Tags: ruby, methods, eigenclass

I was checking to see where methods are defined in Ruby when the definition is performed at the top level and the result is surprising:

```rb
def foo; end

singleton_class != Object # => true
self.class == Object      # => true

m1 = singleton_class.instance_method :foo
# => #<UnboundMethod: Object#foo>

m2 = Object.instance_method :foo
# => #<UnboundMethod: Object#foo>

m1 == m2                  # => true
```

It seems `foo` is defined in two classes at the same time! Any explanations?

Answer (score 0):

The question makes no sense, really. The method is defined just in `Object`. One may get to it through the singleton class, of course, but it is not defined there:

```
singleton_class.instance_methods(false).grep /foo/  # => []
```

Sigh...